# Using SQL 'IN' Operator from HTML drop-down selection

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to use "IN" SQL Operator in HTML Drop-down selection but it returns anything when I run the query.  It works on a single search 
North,East,West...etc., but not working on multi-search for ALL.

HTML:

```
 <select name="region" type="text" id="region" style="font-family:Arial,Sans-Serif;width:180px;"/>
                    <option value="<?=$_GET["region"];?>"></option> 
                    <OPTION VALUE=('S','N','E','W','M','P','I')>ALL
                    <OPTION VALUE="N">North
                    <OPTION VALUE="E">East
                    <OPTION VALUE="S">South
                    <OPTION VALUE="W">West
                    <OPTION VALUE="M">Mapping
                    <OPTION VALUE="P">Photo
                   <OPTION VALUE="I">GIS                     
 </select>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    $db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **.56.**.**)(PORT = ****)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))";
    if($_GET["region"]!="")
    {  
    $objConnect = ocilogon("*****","******",$db);

    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SR4 WHERE AREA IN '".($_GET["region"])."';  

    $objParse = oci_parse ($objConnect, $strSQL);
```

oci_execute ($objParse, OCI_DEFAULT);

?>

Comment: The syntax for IN is incorrect. It is not AREA IN 'N'. It should be AREA IN ('N', 'E'). Why do you need IN to begin with? just to handle S,N ? shouldn't empty AREA handle everything?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used ("S","E") for the test purpose. It should be <OPTION VALUE=('S','N','E','W','M','P','I')>All. I used IN operator because it makes the code neat. It works on a single search like below <OPTION VALUE="N">North, but not working on multisearch <OPTION VALUE=('S','N','E','W','M','P','I')>All

Comment: instead of passing a list of all possible values, why not send just the word 'ALL' and then in PHP do not use any where clause if region is 'ALL'. Note: Your code is subject to SQL injection attack because you are plugging the value from GET directly in SQL statement. Store the value in a variable, sanitize it and then use in your query.

Comment: simple way to check what's wrong with your query is echo your sql statement when select all